# Can I create a custom [video] search engine?

Tags: php, search, google-custom-search

I tried to use 
google custom Search Engine (cse) to search in a specific video sharing websites (like: youtube, Y! video, ... etc). The idea is that a user enters a keyword. then, the results are fetched from those predefined websites. Is it possible to do that? Or those kind of video sharing websites prevent queries from outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what [Google Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/) is for.

1. [Create your search engine](http://www.google.com/cse/manage/create).
2. Set your sites to:

   *.youtube.com/*

   video.yahoo.com/*
3. That's it.

I just did exactly this and it works fine - [here is my test search](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=001702144662740078569%3azn1quwpaaoa&ie=UTF-8&q=cat&sa=Search&siteurl=www.google.com/cse/home?cx=001702144662740078569%3azn1quwpaaoa).

Comment: The problem is that I went through the documentation and tutorials and never find the way to specify the websites to fetch from. Keep in mind that we are talking about VIDEO sharing websites.

Comment: The problem is when I test my search engine in step 2, nothing appears. But when I precedes and copy the code and test it, the results appear. I don't know why and I don't want to know :) . thanks Josh :)

Comment: The test page didn't work for me either but continuing on it worked fine. You're welcome.

Comment: Works for all of YouTube...but is there a way to search a single channel on YT?

Comment: Sure, just change the search URLs to whatever you'd like in step 2, above.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can check the google custom video search engine at http://www.besttubesites.tk which searches videos among top 25 tube sites based on rankings at ranking.com